# Implement both FormsAuthentication and BasicAuthentication ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, single-sign-on, basic-authentication

We currently have a website which has formsauthentication implemented on it.

One of the client requested us to implement a single sign on solution to this website with basic authentication and we want to keep formsauth for the rest of the clients.

So I created a new SSO folder, SSO/SSODefault.aspx page, which will be accessed by only one client and I configured basic authentication in IIS (enabled basic auth and disabled anonymous).

How do I configure/code at application level so that if a user access ~/SSO/SSODefault.aspx I need to perform basic authentication and if user access ~/Login.aspx or ~/any other page except the above SSO page I need to do FormsAuthentication.

Comment: [IIS Mixed authentication](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/iis-mixed-authentication-securing-a-web-site-with-basic-authentication-and-forms-authentication-2/) article for your viewing pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You'll still do FormsAuthentication, but in your SSO page, you'll generate a ticket that the FormsAuthentication method will look at, discover that it is already authenticated, and let that user in.  This [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2004/06/09/ssoformsauth.aspx) should get you started in the right direction.